# Trying to display a hidden nav element when hovering over link via css

Tags: html, css

I have an icon on the top left as shown in the image below:

When I hover over it I would like the side menu (unhidden at the moment) to display, by sliding out and then back in again once off hover, however I'm having trouble getting the css to work.

The problem piece is:
`#nuke_logo > a:hover:nth-child(1) + #nukeSideMenu, #nukeSideMenu:Hover{}`

I've even tried changing something simple like the background color and it's still not working. Must be the syntax, but, I've tried multiple things without success. Can someone see the issue?!

[image]

html snippet:

```
<div id="nuke_logo" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
    <a id="nuke_icon" href="/">
        <img src="/Images/Nuclei/nuclei_md.png">
    </a>
    <a class="" href="/">Nuclei</a>
    <nav id="nukeSideMenu" role="navigation">
        <div>
            <ul id="side-menu" class="nav">
                <li>
                    <a id="lm_CSM" class="">
                        <img alt="CSM" src="/Images/LauncherButtons/CSM_Launcher.png">
                        <span class="menu-title">Customer Services</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a id="lm_ADMIN" class="">
                        <img alt="ADMIN" src="/Images/LauncherButtons/ADMIN_Launcher.png">
                        <span class="menu-title">Administration</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

css snippet:

```
<style>
    #nuke_logo {
        position:relative;
        background:#dbdbdb;
    }
    #nuke_logo a:nth-child(1) {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    #nuke_logo > a:nth-child(1) img {
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin: 10px 5px 1px 0;
        background:#dbdbdb;

        -webkit-transition: 
            -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition:  
            -moz-transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: 
            -o-transform 0.4s ease-in-out; 
        -ms-transition: 
            -ms-transform 0.4s ease-in-out; 
        transition: 
            transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }

    #nuke_logo > a:hover:nth-child(1) img {

        text-decoration: none;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
        -o-transform: scale(1.2);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }

    #nuke_logo a:nth-child(2) {
        color: #525252;
        font-family: "Righteous",cursive;
        display: inline;
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 50px;
    }
    #nuke_logo a:nth-child(2):hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #nuke_logo > a:hover:nth-child(1) + #nukeSideMenu, #nukeSideMenu:Hover {
        width: 55px;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    #nukeSideMenu {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 50px;
        left: 0;
        transition-timing-function: ease;
        -moz-transition-timing-function: ease;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
        -o-transition-timing-function: ease;
        transition-property: width;
        -moz-transition-property: width;
        -webkit-transition-property: width;
        -o-transition-property: width;
        transition-duration: 2s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
        -o-transition-duration: 2s;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Are you trying to do it with just CSS or is JS an option?

Comment: change #nukeSideMenu:Hover{} to #nukeSideMenu:hover{}

Comment: if that doesn't work then create a jsfiddle.net so we can see an example

Comment: Just css please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a working fiddle based on your code

https://jsfiddle.net/y7vufxh8/

instead of `#nuke_logo > a:hover:nth-child(1)` you just need `#nuke_logo a:hover`

also changing width on hover looks bad, use translate3d for nice smooth animations

```
 #nuke_logo a:hover + #nukeSideMenu, #nukeSideMenu:hover {
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    overflow: auto;
}

#nukeSideMenu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate3d(-50%,0,0);
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: @Hank have you checked my solution?

Comment: I have checked it out on jsfiddle looks like it might work, but I've just had some issues with VS not running the app so haven't been able to do any tests.

Comment: ah ok cool well let mew know if it works or you need some more help

Comment: Thanks @Pixelomo, I have replicated your example and it is working to an extent, however when hovering over the corner icon it doesn't display. That's what I was looking for in particular. Any ideas?

Comment: ah I see, the reason that'll be tricky with just css is because the img is a child of the anchor, you're using the + operator to select the anchors sibling #nukesidemenu, it's not a sibling of the anchors img so it wont work. so either you need jquery (overkill) or take the img out of anchor and have it on the same level as #nukesidemenu

Comment: That works now thank you. Using + without fully understanding it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want both your icon and your "Nuclei" label to link to the root of your application, I would recommend that you combine those two items inside one anchor link. That way you can use the hover effect on that link to open your menu below with the CSS sibling selector.

```
// Change this:
<a id="nuke_icon" href="/">
    <img src="/Images/Nuclei/nuclei_md.png">
</a>
<a class="" href="/">Nuclei</a>
<nav id="nukeSideMenu" role="navigation">...

// To this:
<a id="nuke_icon" href="/">
  <img src="/Images/Nuclei/nuclei_md.png" />
  <h1>Nuclei</h1>
</a>
<nav id="nukeSideMenu" role="navigation">...
```

Now we will be able to use the hover on #nuke_icon to make the menu appear.

```
// Add this to your styles for #nukeSideMenu 
#nukeSideMenu {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

// And create this new rule for the hover on the icon with the sibling selector
#nuke_icon:hover + #nukeSideMenu {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, however I excluded the title on purpose, just wanted the a > img to do the work.

Answer (score -1):

If you're hoping to use just CSS then I believe adding this to your stylesheet should do the trick.

```
#nuke_logo:hover #nukeSideMenu {
  width: 55px;
}
```

Comment: This will only work if `#nukeSideMenu` is currently visible. If it is hidden, that will not work.

Comment: In the CSS it looks like to hide it he/she just has width set to 0. So I assumed that's what he/she was using.